# Fast inclusion of the previous value of another type

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table of the following structure:

```
Ordinal   Type
1         A
2         B
3         A
4         B
5         B
6         B
7         A
```

There are two types and the order according to the ordinal matters. I want the following result:

```
Ordinal   Type   Last_A
1         A      1
2         B      1
3         A      3
4         B      3 
5         B      3
6         B      3
7         A      7
```

The new column `Last_A` should contain the last seen `Ordinal` for which the `Type = A`, where last is relative to the order of the `Ordinal`. There may be an arbitrary number of B-rows before another A-row. Is there a performance efficient way of achieving this result? Using a cursor would easily achieve the desired result, but is not feasible due to the large amount of rows I work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a conditional cumulative `max()`:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when t.type = 'A' then ordinal end) over (order by ordinal) as last_A
from t;
```